# Neural network input ordering, does it matter?

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I have seen similar questions, but most involve preprocessing. Do the order in which the input are ordered have any importance. For example, say I have three features with three examples each such as:

```
[0, 0, 0, .5, .5, .5, 1, 1, 1]
```

Would it make any difference if they were ordered like this:

```
[0, .5, 1, 0, .5, 1, 0, .5, 1]
```

i.e does the order of the inputs have any effect at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First your input should be 2D: `(n_examples, n_feat)` so in your case:

```
[[0,.5,1],[0,.5,1],[0,.5,1]]
```

then the ordering of features does not matter as long as it is consistent through the whole training, classification process. So you could as well use:

```
[[.5,1,0],[.5,1,0],[.5,1,0]]
```

as long as you keep putting the first feature last everywhere else.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think most libraries only accept 1d arrays or tuples for inputs.

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: ok don't know that one. maybe add it as tag and mention it again in your post.

Comment: but anyway, however the library handles batches (running several examples at once) the order of features should be irrelevant as long as it is consistent

Answer (score 0):

They are different tensors, of course matters.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: More what? [1,2,3] is different from what [3,2,1] expresses, it's that simple.

Comment: Given enough training examples in the input, wouldn't it learn the same patterns from [1, 2, 3] as [3, 2, 1]?

Comment: No. Unless you mean [shuffle](https://pythonprogramming.net/shuffling-data-learning/)